# Replication Factor to use for system_auth

Tags: configuration, cassandra, replication

When using internal security with Cassandra, what replication factor do you use for system_auth?

The older docs seem to suggest it should be *N*, where *N* is the number of nodes, while the newer ones suggest we should set it to a number greater than 1. I can understand why it makes sense for it to be higher - if a partition occurs and one section doesn't have a replica, nobody can log in.

However, does it need to be all nodes? What are the downsides of setting it to all ndoes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me answer this question by posing another:

If (due to some unforseen event) all of your nodes went down, except for one; would you still want to be able to log into (and use) that node?

This is why I actually do ensure that my system_auth keyspace replicates to all of my nodes.  You can't predict node failure, and in the interests of keeping your application running, it's better safe than sorry.

I don't see any glaring downsides in doing so.  The system_auth keyspace isn't very big (mine is 20kb) so it doesn't take up a lot of space.  The only possible scenario, would be if one of the nodes is down, and a write operation is made to a column family in system_auth (in which case, I think the write gets rejected...depending on your write consistency).  Either way system_auth isn't a very write-heavy keyspace.  So you'll be ok as long as you don't plan on performing user maintenance during a node failure.

Setting the replication factor of system_auth to the number of nodes in the cluster should be ok.  At the very least, I would say you should make sure it replicates to all of your data centers.

In case you were still wondering about this part of your question:

> The older docs seem to suggest it should be N where n is the number of nodes, while the newer ones suggest we should set it to a number greater than 1."

I stumbled across this today in the 2.1 documentation [Configuring Authentication](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/security/security_config_native_authenticate_t.html):

> Increase the replication factor for the system_auth keyspace to N
>   (number of nodes).

Just making sure that recommendation was clear.

**Addendum 20181108**

So I originally answered this back when the largest cluster I had ever managed had 10 nodes.  Four years later, after spending three of those managing large (100+) node clusters for a major retailer, my opinions on this have changed somewhat.  I can say that I no longer agree with this statement of mine from four years ago.

> This is why I actually do ensure that my system_auth keyspace replicates to all of my nodes.

A few times on mind-to-large (20-50 nodes) clusters , we have deployed `system_auth` with RFs as high as 8.  It works as long as you're not moving nodes around, and assumes that the default cassandra/cassandra user is no longer in-play.

The drawbacks were seen on clusters which have a tendency to fluctuate in size.  Of course, clusters which change in size usually do so because of high throughput requirements across multiple providers, further complicating things.  We noticed that occasionally, the application teams would report auth failures on such clusters.  We were able to quickly rectify these situation, by running a `SELECT COUNT(*)` on all `system_auth` tables, thus forcing a read repair.  But the issue would tend to resurface the next time we added/removed several nodes.

Due to issues that can happen with larger clusters which fluctuate in size, **we now treat** `system_auth` **like we do any other keyspace.**  That is, we set `system_auth`'s RF to 3 in each DC.

That seems to work really well.  It gets you around the problems that come with having too many replicas to manage in a high-throughput, dynamic environment.  After all, if RF=3 is good enough for your application's data, it's probably good enough for `system_auth`.

Comment: Yeah...I can see that. I guess it only becomes an issue for large clusters where the odd node is down regularly. Can't see us changing auth stuff very frequently...might as well go with ALL :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason the recommendation changed was that a quorum query would require responses from over half of your nodes to fullfill.  So if you accidentally left Cassandra user active and you have 80 nodes - we need 41 responses.

Whilst it's good practice to avoid using the super user like that - you'd be surprised how often it's still out there.