# What is Cassandra system_auth replication factor 2 means?

Tags: cassandra

As i read and understood from official cassandra document and from other posts here when we configure system_auth replication factor is 1.

But i would like to understood, how the system_auth replication works if i configure value as system_auth replication = 2?

which two nodes will maintain replicas?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891353/replication-factor-to-use-for-system-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be two copies of the system_auth keyspace spread across ALL of your nodes. That way, if one goes down, the data is still available on another node. Different entries to system_auth may be stored on different nodes, but there will always be two copies.

If your replication factor = the number of nodes, then each node will hold all the system_auth data. If your replication factor > number of nodes, you are gaining nothing, since all nodes already have a full copy of the data, no extra safety here. If your replication factor < number of nodes, no node will hold a complete copy of the data, but it will hold a portion of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Samantha. I understood your reply but still trying to visualize how different it is if we have configured system_auth replication as 3 Vs system_auth replication as 2.

Comment: I added more description to my original answer, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks lot Samantha. this is really a great elaboration. I understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here system_auth replication = 2 means data of system_auth will be replicated on 2 nodes(total 2 copy of data) on cluster. if one node goes down then you can also able to login and authenticate the node.
you may increase the replication factor as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pandey. As we increase the replication factory, Could you please describe how will the authentication works in brief.                                               Like, what if i have configured system_auth RF as 2 and 3.

Comment: if you increase the replication factor in that case data of system_auth will be replicated on all 3 nodes if we are assuming 3 node cluster and in any case both two nodes go down then also you can connect Cassandra server through cqlsh but query depends upon consistency and other factors.

Comment: Thanks Pandey helping me in understanding the concept. great help.