# system_auth replicates without changing replication_factor, so why change it?

Tags: cassandra

I have a `PasswordAuthenticator` login, user = `cassandra`, with `system_auth` RF = 1 and 2 non-seed nodes. When I changed the password, it propagated to the non-seed nodes even though RF = 1.   So why change the RF?  `(The reason I ask is: I noticed if I change it to 3 before the other nodes are up --> I can't login: QUORUM error, so this is a bootstrapping question)`

```
cassandra@cqlsh:system_auth> SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces;

 keyspace_name      | durable_writes | replication
--------------------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        system_auth |           True |   {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems can happen if you don't change it:

1. In a multi-node cluster, if the node responsible for your user/role data crashes, you won't be able to log in.
2. In a multi-DC cluster, if you attempt to connect with your application using a "local" data center, you will only be able to connect to nodes in the DC containing your user/role data.  This is because `SimpleStrategy` is *not* DC aware.  Not changing it will also only store one replica in the cluster, which will only be in a single DC.  Login attempts on the other DCs will fail.

In short, I recommend:

- Never use `SimpleStrategy`.  It's not useful for production MDHA (multi-datacenter high availability), so why build a lower environment with it?
- Set the RF on `system_auth` to number of nodes, but no more than 3.
- Creating an additional super user, and changing the password of the cassandra/cassandra user...never using it again.  The cassandra/cassandra user triggers some special things inside of cqlsh to operate at `QUORUM`, by default.  If nodes crash, you don't want the extra problems which that opens the door for.

Here's a related answer, which should help: [Replication Factor to use for system_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891353/replication-factor-to-use-for-system-auth)