# cassandra 3.11.9 system_auth need to be SimpleStrategy or NetworkTopologyStrategy on production env?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

What is the recommended for cassandra (apache) 3.11.9 system_auth? need to be `SimpleStrategy` or `NetworkTopologyStrategy`? And with how much RF?

We have cassandra with 1 dc (2-3 AWS racks with EC2_snitch + dynamic_snitch disabled).  Most queries running on consistency level local_one).  Today our `system_auth` keyspace configured `SimpleStrategy` with RF 3.  In a lot of queries, we are wasting time on (tracing):

```
Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-X]
```

As part of an attempt to solve our problems we also increased the parameters:

roles_validity_in_ms, permissions_validity_in_ms, credentials_validity_in_ms, permissions_cache_max_entries.

Can queries latency problems be connected to system_auth keyspace configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this question a while ago, which is similar:
[Replication Factor to use for system_auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891353/replication-factor-to-use-for-system-auth/25892077#25892077)

> Due to issues that can happen with larger clusters which fluctuate in size, we now treat system_auth like we do any other keyspace. That is, we set system_auth's RF to 3 in each DC.

**tl;dr;**, if you're using `NetworkTopologyStrategy` on your non-system keyspaces, then you should also be using it for `system_auth`.  Same with your RF; I'd always match the RF of `system_auth` with that of my "normal" keyspaces, as well.

No, the replication strategy and RF used on `system_auth` does not typically cause query latency.  That is of course, unless any of the Security cache settings have been altered.  10 years of working with Cassandra, I've never had to change those: https://docs.datastax.com/en/security/5.1/security/secAuthCacheSettings.html

> queries wasting time on (tracing): "Executing single-partition query on roles [ReadStage-X]"

This statement got me thinking: Are you tracing queries in cqlsh while logged in as the default `cassandra` user?  That user *does* trigger some cqlsh operations to execute at QUORUM.  Could also be that maybe the query consistency and connection consistency are set differently.  Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for answer Aaron,
We are using NetworkTopologyStrategy on non-system keyspaces with RF 3.
About the changes on security caches, we done that after very high read rate on role_permissions & roles tables on nodes.
The change significantly lowered the readings. our application works with spot instances that open and close connections throughout the day in a fairly active way, (we know it is better otherwise but can not change it at the moment). we have around 350 connections per node in peak time. But there are new connections and disconnection of old connections all the time.
Thanks!

Comment: About the trace, I take from debug.log some slow queries and try to do trace with cassandra\root user (not the application user), Could it be related to roles ReadStage?

Comment: The default `cassandra` user should have its password changed when the cluster is created, and it should never be used again.  Create a new super user account for any future admin tasks.  Also, it makes sense to run your traces with the same user that runs the queries, just to eliminate any discrepancies.

Comment: I may not have been clear, the user I used is root (a new super user account for any future admin tasks), and I will try trace with the same user like the application running. Thanks!